# Best Video Player which easily integrates with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

Tried Flowplayer, doesn't seem great, is JW Player better ? Any other suggestion ? Especially need to be able to manage TimeCode with Frame support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a control or a means to play videos? You can interact with videos much better than most ActiveX video players by using Silverlight.

Comment: Cannot use activex must work on any flash browser that is why :)

But finally have managed to make Flowplayer works on asp.net thanks.

Comment: @user310291 - you should add your comment as an answer and mark it as answer instead of marking the one that doesn't fits your question. This would help others to get a correct or most appropriate answer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use this player from code project it's compatible with asp.net and it's free 
you can find it on [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Online-Video-Player.aspx)